# Type of "or" in the sentence , "Addition or subtraction of 2 integers is either even or odd. "

Tags: logic

I want to know the type of "or" in the above sentence . By type of or I mean is it exclusive or inclusive ? Also since here "or" occurs 2 times please tell the type of "or" for both of them . I think that first one should be inclusive and second one should be exclusive . Please do explain your answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is a little clumsy/unclear/wrong. The intended meaning is that the *sum* and *difference* of two integers have the same parity.

Formally:

$$(\text{even}(a+b)\land\text{even}{(a-b)})\lor(\text{odd}(a+b)\land\text{odd}{(a-b)}).$$

As $\text{even}$ and $\text{odd}$ are mutually exclusive by definition, this is strictly equivalent to

$$(\text{even}(a+b)\land\text{even}{(a-b)})\oplus(\text{odd}(a+b)\land\text{odd}{(a-b)}).$$

The first "or" is grammatical (informal) and serves as a shorthand to avoid repeating what follows, **but it should be an "and"***.

The second "or" is mathematical as it combines propositions "is even", "is odd", and is made explicitly exclusive by the reinforcement with "either".

---

*With an "or", the meaning is

$$(\text{even}(a+b)\lor\text{even}{(a-b)})\lor(\text{odd}(a+b)\lor\text{odd}{(a-b)}),$$

which is a useless tautology, as any number is even or odd.

Answer (score 0):

Either or always means exclusive. I.e. even or odd but not both. Whereas or always means inclusive i.e. addition or subtraction or both. And the explanation is that it is so by convention.